# How to use a material stepper in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, frontend, angular-material2

I'm currently somewhat new to Angular and I'm trying to figure out how to make a simple stepper that goes (1) -- (2) -- (3).

I have the html down as app.component.html

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <mat-step label="Step 1">
        step 1
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Step 2">
        step 2
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

However, what do I need to import and do in typescript to make this work?  I have app.component.ts as

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper;
  changeStep(index: number) {
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
  }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzbdvp?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: import MatStepperModule to resolve the issue

Comment: @Naga Sai A Something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jneewj?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts  however I want to know how to fix up my code to do that

Answer (score 7):

Import the following components of angular material and use the same code that you have

**Module.ts**

```
import { MatStepperModule, MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...    
        MatStepperModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,                        
    ],...
```

**HTML**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear"> 
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
       <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">  
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>  
        <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Solve</button>        
      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="Any input" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>          
        <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>        
      </form>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel icon>Done</ng-template>
      You are now done.      
      <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" >Done</button>      
    </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

....
export class ComponentStepper{

  isLinear = true;
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){} 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({     
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
}
```

This is a complete [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vufhvk?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.html) even with FormGruop validations

Comment: Where do you import ThemeModule from?

Comment: Do not Import ThemeModule. Sorry

Comment: I just get an error: Can't bind to 'linear' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-horizontal-stepper'.
1. If 'mat-horizontal-stepper' is an Angular component and it has 'linear' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: I edit my post, there are a complete demo  take a look in **module.ts** and **component.ts**

Comment: Did you get it? @user10109

Comment: No, I just get errors when I tried to replicate it.  If you could post all the components that make it work that would be great

Comment: Same as a comment above: Can't bind to 'linear' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-horizontal-stepper'

Comment: The example of `module.ts` was very useful but didn't quite get me there. I had to add one more import too: `ReactiveFormsModule`, from `'@angular/forms'`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Along with Abel Valdez's answer dont forget to import **CdkStepperModule** to stepper to work

```
 import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
```

and

```
imports: [
    ...
    CdkStepperModule,
    MatStepperModule,
```